# Excellent Local Ring: Properties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, formal-completions

Let $(R,m)$ be an [***excellent***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_ring) local ring. Denote by $\phi: R \to \hat{R}$ the canonical completion map and $f: \operatorname{Spec}(\hat{R}) \to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ the induced map of Specs.

Let $Q \in \operatorname{Spec}(\hat{R})$ and $\phi^{-1}(Q)= f(Q)=:P \in \operatorname{Spec}(R) $.

I'm looking for a rigorous proof for following statement:

Let $S$ be the property ***regular, reduced, Cohen-Macaulay*** or ***Gorenstein***.

Then $R_P$ has property $S$ if and only if $\hat{R}_Q$ has S.

Comment: Did you do any searching on your own? [EGA IV part II](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1965__24__5_0.pdf) section 7.8 is the original source and should have most/all of the claims you seek. (This is cited on the wikipedia page from your other question which I took the liberty of inserting in to this question - your copy/paste of the introduction left off the link.)

Comment: Thank you, have overlooked that :)